# jQuery script for image change, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change src of in img, I coded as below, but it's not working, what's wrong?

```
<img id='logo_image'/>
<span onclick='$(logo_image).attr("src", "images/logo_orange.png");'>click me</span>
```

Comment: please show the corresponding HTML code!

Comment: the logo_image is a variable ? defined ?

Comment: What is `logo_image`?  That needs to be a valid css selector

Comment: Also, give the span an ID and use script to assign the click event handler.  Inline is an anagram of fugly.

Comment: @mdesdev I wish comments had a downvote button

Comment: @Archer Me too, bad thinking ;)

Answer (score 4):

It might be the problem with your selector.

If it is id use    `$('#logo_image')`

If it is class use  `$('.logo_image')`

Answer (score 2):

First up you're trying to use a variable `logo_image` when you should be using a string starting with `#` to indicate you want to select by id:

```
onclick='$("#logo_image").attr("src", "images/logo_orange.png");'
```

Secondly, it would be better not to use an inline `onclick` attribute if you can help it:

```
<img id='logo_image'/>
<span>click me</span>

<script>
$("span").click(function() {
   $("#logo_image").attr("src", "images/logo_orange.png");
});
</script>
```

...where ideally the span element would have some id or something to select it by.

Thirdly, don't make span elements clickable in the first place unless you don't care about making your page accessible to people who can't (or who choose not to) use a mouse or other pointing device. Better to use an anchor (which you can style as you see fit) so that the user can tab to it and activate it with the keyboard:

```
<img id='logo_image'/>
<a href="#">click me</a>

<script>
$("a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#logo_image").attr("src", "images/logo_orange.png");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have specified the image as an id, you will need to reference the image via the following code:

```
$('#logo_image')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you aren't probably setting the object to `logo_image` variable.

I suggest changing it to:

`<span onclick='$("#logo_image").attr("src", "images/logo_orange.png");'>click me</span>`

`logo-_image` should be the `id` of that image.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want refer to the name of the id, you have to wrap the `logo_image` in quotes, otherwise Javascript will treat it as variable.

```
$('#logo_image')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like this:

```
<img id="logo_image" src="" />
<span onclick='$("#logo_image").attr("src", "images/logo_orange.png");'>
    click me
</span>
```

if you have an `img` with a `id` named `logo_image`
if your `img` has the css class `logo_image` you have to write:

```
<img class="logo_image" src="" />
<span onclick='$(".logo_image").attr("src", "images/logo_orange.png");'>
    click me
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure u use the right quotes in the javascript part.
Also use $('#logo_image') selector to get the image by id.
I made a jsfiddle for you to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ltfa/

```
<span onclick="$('#logo_image').attr('src', 'images/logo_orange.png');">click me</span>
```